# Getting Environment variables in .net core react app to show, using azure to set environment variables

Tags: reactjs, azure, asp.net-core, single-page-application

I have set my environment variables within the configuration section of the azure web app.

however i cannot access these environment variables from `process.env.` within my react app.

is there another step i need to take because the app is a .net core web app using a react spa?

I have looked online and cant seem to find anything that will work for me.

I asumed these will auto get mapped if with the keyword REACT_APP at the start of my env vars

Comment: You're trying to get these environment variables during build time, not runtime, right?

Comment: Yes my release pipeline sets them when publishing to azure. When my app starts I expect to be able to grab them.

Comment: got it, you can only access there environment variables during build time, because when your application runs on the browser there is no process.env variable. When your app is running it just have a static value of this variable that webpack or any other module bundler have bundled for you. So if you really need to change something in your application based on this (API URL for example), you need to do this on the same environment and before you run "npm run build"